# What's the equivalent of "rmdir -p" under Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a command line under Windows console that does `rmdir -p /dir/`

Quoting the manual:

```
-p, --parents   Remove explicit parent directories if being emptied
```

Comment: **If the directories are all empty**, then `rd /s UltimateParent` will have the same effect, but it will remove files as well as directories. If you want to remove only empty directories, you will need to use a `for` loop, though you can create a batch file with the loop in it.

Comment: @AFH If the directories are all empty, the graphical shell works as well (hit delete). In my case they are many and *mostly* empty. I may have to go for a batch script...